# Can't Remove Logical Drive/Array from HP P400

Tags: redhat, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

This is my first post here. Thank you in advance for any assistance with this matter.

I'm trying to remove a logical drive (logical drive 2) and an array (array "B") from my Smart Array P400. The host is a DL580 G5 running 64-bit Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 (Tikanga). I am unable to remove the array using either hpacucli or cpqacuxe. I believe it is because of "OS Status: LOCKED". The file system that lives on this array has been unmounted. I do not want to reboot the host. Is there some way to "release" this logical drive so I can remove the array? Note that I do not need to preserve the data on logical drive 2. I intend to physically remove the drives from the machine and replace them with larger drives.

I'm using the cciss kernel module that ships with Red Hat 5.7.

Here is some information pertaining to the host and the P400 configuration:

```
[root@gort ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 (Tikanga)



[root@gort ~]# uname -a
Linux gort 2.6.18-274.el5 #1 SMP Fri Jul 8 17:36:59 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux



[root@gort ~]# rpm -qa | egrep '^(hp|cpq)'
cpqacuxe-9.30-15.0
hp-health-9.25-1551.7.rhel5
hpsmh-7.1.2-3
hpdiags-9.3.0-466
hponcfg-3.1.0-0
hp-snmp-agents-9.25-2384.8.rhel5
hpacucli-9.30-15.0

[root@gort ~]# hpacucli
HP Array Configuration Utility CLI 9.30.15.0
Detecting Controllers...Done.
Type "help" for a list of supported commands.
Type "exit" to close the console.

=> ctrl all show config detail

Smart Array P400 in Slot 0 (Embedded)
   Bus Interface: PCI
   Slot: 0
   Cache Serial Number: PA82C0J9SVW34U
   RAID 6 (ADG) Status: Enabled
   Controller Status: OK
   Hardware Revision: D
   Firmware Version: 7.22
   Rebuild Priority: Medium
   Expand Priority: Medium
   Surface Scan Delay: 15 secs
   Surface Scan Mode: Idle
   Wait for Cache Room: Disabled
   Surface Analysis Inconsistency Notification: Disabled
   Post Prompt Timeout: 0 secs
   Cache Board Present: True
   Cache Status: OK
   Cache Ratio: 25% Read / 75% Write
   Drive Write Cache: Disabled
   Total Cache Size: 256 MB
   Total Cache Memory Available: 208 MB
   No-Battery Write Cache: Disabled
   Cache Backup Power Source: Batteries
   Battery/Capacitor Count: 1
   Battery/Capacitor Status: OK
   SATA NCQ Supported: True


      Logical Drive: 1
         Size: 136.7 GB
         Fault Tolerance: RAID 1
         Heads: 255
         Sectors Per Track: 32
         Cylinders: 35132
         Strip Size: 128 KB
         Full Stripe Size: 128 KB
         Status: OK
         Caching:  Enabled
         Unique Identifier: 600508B100184A395356573334550002
         Disk Name: /dev/cciss/c0d0
         Mount Points: /boot 101 MB, /tmp 7.8 GB, /usr 3.9 GB, /usr/local 2.0 GB, /var 3.9 GB, / 2.0 GB, /local 113.2 GB
         OS Status: LOCKED
         Logical Drive Label: A0027AA78DEE
         Mirror Group 0:
            physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
         Mirror Group 1:
            physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
         Drive Type: Data
   Array: A
      Interface Type: SAS
      Unused Space: 0  MB
      Status: OK
      Array Type: Data



      physicaldrive 1I:1:1
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 1
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SAS
         Size: 146 GB
         Rotational Speed: 10000
         Firmware Revision: HPDE
         Serial Number: 3NM57RF40000983878FX
         Model: HP      DG146BB976
         Current Temperature (C): 29
         Maximum Temperature (C): 35
         PHY Count: 2
         PHY Transfer Rate: Unknown, Unknown

      physicaldrive 1I:1:2
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 2
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SAS
         Size: 146 GB
         Rotational Speed: 10000
         Firmware Revision: HPDE
         Serial Number: 3NM55VQC000098388524
         Model: HP      DG146BB976
         Current Temperature (C): 29
         Maximum Temperature (C): 36
         PHY Count: 2
         PHY Transfer Rate: Unknown, Unknown


      Logical Drive: 2
         Size: 546.8 GB
         Fault Tolerance: RAID 5
         Heads: 255
         Sectors Per Track: 32
         Cylinders: 65535
         Strip Size: 64 KB
         Full Stripe Size: 256 KB
         Status: OK
         Caching:  Enabled
         Parity Initialization Status: Initialization Completed
         Unique Identifier: 600508B100184A395356573334550003
         Disk Name: /dev/cciss/c0d1
         Mount Points: None
         OS Status: LOCKED
         Logical Drive Label: A5C9C6F81504
         Drive Type: Data

   Array: B
      Interface Type: SAS
      Unused Space: 0  MB
      Status: OK
      Array Type: Data



      physicaldrive 1I:1:3
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 3
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SAS
         Size: 146 GB
         Rotational Speed: 10000
         Firmware Revision: HPDE
         Serial Number: 3NM2H5PE00009802NK19
         Model: HP      DG146ABAB4
         Current Temperature (C): 30
         Maximum Temperature (C): 37
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: Unknown

      physicaldrive 1I:1:4
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 4
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SAS
         Size: 146 GB
         Rotational Speed: 10000
         Firmware Revision: HPDE
         Serial Number: 3NM28YY400009750MKPJ
         Model: HP      DG146ABAB4
         Current Temperature (C): 31
         Maximum Temperature (C): 36
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 3.0Gbps

      physicaldrive 2I:1:5
         Port: 2I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 5
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SAS
         Size: 146 GB
         Rotational Speed: 10000
         Firmware Revision: HPDE
         Serial Number: 3NM2FGYV00009802N3GN
         Model: HP      DG146ABAB4
         Current Temperature (C): 30
         Maximum Temperature (C): 38
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: Unknown

      physicaldrive 2I:1:6
         Port: 2I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 6
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SAS
         Size: 146 GB
         Rotational Speed: 10000
         Firmware Revision: HPDE
         Serial Number: 3NM8AFAK00009920MMV1
         Model: HP      DG146BB976
         Current Temperature (C): 31
         Maximum Temperature (C): 41
         PHY Count: 2
         PHY Transfer Rate: Unknown, Unknown

      physicaldrive 2I:1:7
         Port: 2I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 7
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SAS
         Size: 146 GB
         Rotational Speed: 10000
         Firmware Revision: HPDE
         Serial Number: 3NM2FJQD00009801MSHQ
         Model: HP      DG146ABAB4
         Current Temperature (C): 29
         Maximum Temperature (C): 39
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: Unknown
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the array or delete it? If you no longer care about the data, the approach is different than if you need to preserve the data on Array B.

Comment: I do not need to preserve the data. I'm going to remove the drives and replace them with larger ones. How do I "unlock" the logical disk so I can remove it and the array?

Comment: I'll answer a little later today.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to download a *slightly older* version of the `hpacucli` utility. My recommendation for you would be to use [version 9.0.24.0 of the hpacucli tool](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?swItem=MTX-43192cb759444c33a5e8bdefb1&lang=en&cc=us&mode=3&). The full application [change log is here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?swItem=MTX-37499d407ba04b078396a44a7d&lang=en&cc=us&mode=5&).

Run an `rpm -e hpacucli` to remove your existing copy and then install the downloaded version manually.

The RPM installation notes for the current hpacucli state:
 
*LOCKING NOTE: The locking mechanism starting with versions 9.10.X.X, are not compatible with prior versions of the applications. Therefore, mixing older and newer versions of the various applications (ACU, HPACUCLI, HPACUSCRIPTING) is not recommended.*

I noticed this message as I was prepping a test environment. I noticed that my older systems did not show the locking status on the logical drives. Apparently, this was changed in the June 2012 revision of `hpacucli`. Step back to an older version and you should be able to remove the unmounted volume/array.

Something like: `hpacucli controller slot=0 array B delete` should work from there.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot tomorrow and update this thread.

Comment: Still no joy. hpacucli 9.0.24.0 reports "OS Status: LOCKED" for logical drive 2, and I cannot remove it.

I wonder if
        blockdev --rmparts /dev/cciss/c0d1
will free it?

Comment: Then go to the [version before that](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=0&prodSeriesId=0&swItem=MTX-c029e034abc54269a327a9b9c7&mode=3) then. I linked to the full list of downloads. Also, stop the HP SNMP Agents with `service hp-snmp-agents stop` before you try this.

Comment: I think as long as `/dev/cciss/c0d1p1` appears in `/proc/partitions`, this will not be possible. Removing the partition `/dev/cciss/c0d1p1` has no effect, because, for some reason, the kernel can't be notified of the change: `BLKRRPART: Device or resource busy`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have anything referencing the old filesystem? Did you check with `lsof` and such? What does `partprobe` output?

Comment: `lsof` and `fuser` come back clean. `partprobe /dev/cciss/c0d1` exits cleanly, but `/dev/cciss/c0d1p1` remains in `/proc/partitions`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found the answer: you need to unmap from dm table. in my case, the RAID array was used as LVM PV.

To list mapped devices:

```
# dmsetup info -C
Name             Maj Min Stat Open Targ Event  UUID
vg1-lv1    253   2 L--w    1    1      0 LVM-c36u77EBvd47dEONRbkrsf4Jn6IcJPbkV23hye2Mwbf4Ry8N8kyUhVzyv6253nxs
vg1-lv2    253   0 L--w    1    1      0 LVM-c36u77EBvd47dEONRbkrsf4Jn6IcJPbkXtZFGKULrB9uG8ufng3v9x6nGyDfQoxZ
vg2-lv1    253   3 L--w    0    1      0 LVM-awXTmx1Bt18fxl1kealUgBMeAuRpOrqU5AeLdyrh1I0mYv5pMQTrgj7xR8mDUnK2
vg1-lv3    253   1 L--w    1    1      0 LVM-c36u77EBvd47dEONRbkrsf4Jn6IcJPbk8c4PaxXjnZbwudLpewNsFl63E7zOhl4T
```

Find the one you want to remove and execute:

```
# dmsetup remove vg2-lv1
```

Then you can remove the array